# Find tag <a> and put a word in an element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want:

if inside tag `<li>` there is no tag `<a>`, then - insert word "Empty" into `<div class="tooltip"> </div>`.

How can do i do it with jQuery?

```
<ol>
    <li><input name="hotel_id[]" value="14" style="display:none;">
    <div class="tooltip" style="top: 439px; left: 717px; display: none; ">
    </div>
    <a href="" class="tool_tip" title="ok">Hello</a></li>

    <li><input name="hotel_id[]" value="5" style="display:none;">
    <div class="tooltip" style="opacity: 0.9; top: 439px; left: 717px; display: none; ">
    </div>
    <a href="" class="tool_tip" title="">How</a></li>

    <li><input name="hotel_id[]" value="4" style="display:none;">
    <div class="tooltip" style="top: 439px; left: 717px; display: none; opacity: 0.9; ">
    </div>
    <a href="" class="tool_tip" title="">Are</a></li>

    <li><input name="hotel_id[]" value="3" style="display:none;">
    <div class="tooltip" style="opacity: 0.9; top: 439px; left: 717px; display: none; ">
    </div>
    <a href="" class="tool_tip" title="">Help</a></li>

    <li><input name="hotel_id[]" value="2" style="display:none;">
    <div class="tooltip" style="top: 439px; left: 717px; display: none; ">
         // I want append here word "Empty" that there is not tag a in li
    </div></li>

    <li><input name="hotel_id[]" value="1" style="display:none;">
    <div class="tooltip" style="top: 439px; left: 717px; display: none; ">
         // I want appen here word "Empty" that there is not tag a in li
    </div></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look after :not and :has:

```
$("li:not(:has(a))").find(".tooltip").html("Empty").removeAttr("style");
```

I remove the style attribute on .tooltip, if you dont need that just change it to show() instead to show the .tooltip:

```
$("li:not(:has(a))").find(".tooltip").html("Empty").show();
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/uyuwoy/edit

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
$('ol li').not(':has(a)').find('.tooltip').html('Empty');
```